# Python Flask how to get values for items such as DN for LDAP authentication

Tags: python, ldap

I am using https://flask-ldap3-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html#basic-application which comes with a sample script that contains the following

```
# Hostname of your LDAP Server
app.config['LDAP_HOST'] = 'ad.mydomain.com'

# Base DN of your directory
app.config['LDAP_BASE_DN'] = 'dc=mydomain,dc=com'

# Users DN to be prepended to the Base DN
app.config['LDAP_USER_DN'] = 'ou=users'

# Groups DN to be prepended to the Base DN
app.config['LDAP_GROUP_DN'] = 'ou=groups'

# The RDN attribute for your user schema on LDAP
app.config['LDAP_USER_RDN_ATTR'] = 'cn'
```

I presume I can get `app.config['LDAP_HOST']` by running `nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.mydomain.co.uk` and using that value but how would I go about the rest?

I've ran `get-aduser jo.bloggs -Properties *` but this gives me so may values I'm not sure where to start

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using SRV records is a good method – much better than assuming "ad.example.com" directly as the server to use. (Even though that name does point to all DCs, you wouldn't be able to use TLS or Kerberos with it as both rely on the server's exact name being provided.)

Note that directory servers can come and go, so the results of the SRV lookup should not be hardcoded in the app.

**`app.config['LDAP_BASE_DN']`**

The directory's base DN (of which there can be multiple) can be found by reading the rootDSE entry – some LDAP libraries have a built-in function for that, while in others you just make a search at **empty DN** i.e. `""` as the base (and `BASE` as the search scope, as is usual for reading a single entry).

In the rootDSE entry, the `namingContexts` attribute will contain the base DNs of all partitions in that server, while `defaultNamingContext` points specifically at the "primary" partition which contains user objects and such.

```
$ ldapsearch -x -b "" -s base \* +
dn: 
defaultNamingContext: DC=ad,DC=example,DC=com
namingContexts: DC=ad,DC=example,DC=com
namingContexts: DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=ad,DC=example,DC=com
namingContexts: DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=ad,DC=example,DC=com
```

For Active Directory you can take a shortcut and mechanically generate a DN out of the AD domain name, simply by converting each DNS domain component into a `dc=` attribute (e.g. `dc=mydomain,dc=co,dc=uk` from your own example).

(The same method is *not* guaranteed to work for other LDAP directories, however, as there's no requirement that a directory even use dc= for the base entry at all – for example, it's entirely valid to use `o=Example Inc.` as the base – so you should always look at the rootDSE to be sure.)

**`app.config['LDAP_USER_DN'] = 'ou=users'`**

"Users DN to be prepended to the Base DN" *highly* depends on how each individual directory is managed. You have to look at the directory's contents (e.g. via Apache Directory Studio or at least via dsa.msc) to get an idea of the layout.

It is also possible that the directory *will not* have a single common branch which contains all users, and that there will be multiple OUs or other containers created directly below the root DN. In that situation, tell Flask to *not* prepend anything here, and to perform user searches across the entire directory.

The same goes for groups; they might be under a single branch, or they might be scattered all over the place.

**`app.config['LDAP_USER_RDN_ATTR'] = 'cn'`**

"RDN" refers to the leftmost component of a DN (e.g. `DC=ad` is the RDN of `DC=ad,DC=example,DC=com`). "The RDN attribute for your user schema on LDAP" is usually either `CN` or `uid` and is generally the same across the entire directory, so you can determine it by looking at the DN of your own user account's LDAP entry. (In Active Directory it is practically always `cn`.)